# How to center navigation items while the nav remains full-width?

Tags: html, css

I have a limitation for my content (div with width: 1000px). I also have a fixed navigation with several items (logo, navigation list and social media icons). I need the navigation to stay full page (white background), but the items to be centered within the 1000px in the center (so it's symmetrical).

I tried adding another div within the header and set the width to 1000px, but it breaks my whole header. I tried removing and adding margins and paddings, but it's not a permanent solution (addint a padding-right to the icons will only work for one size of the screen). Moving the 1000px div to the top results in not a full-width navigation.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:500&display=swap');

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

li,
a {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 0 0;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #007991, #78ffd6);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 65px;
}

header {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0;
  background: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
}

.navlinks {
  list-style: none;
}

.navlinks a {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 0;
}

.navlinks a {
  transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
  line-height: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.navlinks a:hover {
  color: #000033;
  background: #73FAD3;
}

.Inhalt {
  background: white;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="header-branding">
      <img class="header-logo" src="" alt="LOGO">
    </div>
    <nav class="navlinks">
      <a href="#">Menu1</a>
      <a href="#">Menu2</a>
      <a href="#">Menu3</a>
      <a href="#">Menu4</a>
    </nav>
    <ul class="socialmediaicons">
      <a class="fa fa-facebook" href="#"></a>
      <a class="fa fa-twitter" href="#"></a>
      <a class="fa fa-spotify" href="#"></a>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <div class="Inhalt">
    <article>
      <h3>Article 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </article>
  </div>
</body>
```

You can see the code here:

https://jsfiddle.net/h423L8ro/3/

How can I get the items to be symmetrical to the 1000px div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want

I add a div inside your header and then I added style to it, this way it will not break your header.

```css
.navbar {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="header-branding">
        <img class="header-logo" src="" alt="LOGO">
      </div>
      <nav class="navlinks">
        <a href="#">Menu1</a>
        <a href="#">Menu2</a>
        <a href="#">Menu3</a>
        <a href="#">Menu4</a>
      </nav>
      <ul class="socialmediaicons">
        <a class="fa fa-facebook" href="#"></a>
        <a class="fa fa-twitter" href="#"></a>
        <a class="fa fa-spotify" href="#"></a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Also, you should change the width from your header to `100%` instead of `100vw`, because `vw` doesn't consider the scroll bar width.

Comment: That's exactly what i needed! Thank you so much! Not only was it a very fast answer, but also a very good one. 

I tried something similar, but it didn't work out. I guess I used the wrong display. 

Thanks for the tip with the percentage, will try to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Set it's width to (100/number of items)-(logowidth/number of items)%

So if you set logo width to 4%, your menu items will be 24%

```css
.navlinks {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
}
.header-logo {
  width:4%;
}
.navlinks a {
  transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
  line-height: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 24%;
  text-align:center;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

check this: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f8pwsvq0/)

Comment: Sadly, that's not working for me at all. It corrupts the spacings just as much as with my first attempts. But check out @Felipe Yáñez answer, it's exactly what I was looking for. 

Thank you anyway for the quick respond and trying to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using width in px, try it using percentage. To make a dynamic and responsive site (according to the device) you need to declare dimensions in percentage (preferred).
Try it with:

```
{
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
display: inline-block;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've always preferred this implementation, but it's more a preference.

```css
.navbar {
    clear: both;
}

.header-branding {
    float: left
}

.navlinks {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.navlinks a {
    display: inline-block;
}

.socialmediaicons {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.socialmediaicons a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="header-branding">
            <img class="header-logo"  width="50" src="http://www.nashikproperty.com/uploads/builder-logo/default-logo.png" alt="LOGO">
        </div>
        <ul class="socialmediaicons">
            <a class="fa fa-facebook" href="#"></a>
            <a class="fa fa-twitter" href="#"></a>
            <a class="fa fa-spotify" href="#"></a>
        </ul>
        <nav class="navlinks">
            <a href="#">Menu1</a>
            <a href="#">Menu2</a>
            <a href="#">Menu3</a>
            <a href="#">Menu4</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```